Marginal distribution bivariate Markov chain
Let's say I have a Markov chain on $X \times X'$ with transition probabilities $P((x,x'), (y,y')) = P(X_{n} = y, X_{n}' = y' | X_{n-1} = x, X_{n-1}' = x')$.
What is the most general way to compute transition probabilities $P(x,y)$ and $P(x', y')$ (here I am assuming that the 'marginal' chains are in fact Markov chains)? One issue that I can think of is that summing over $y$ or $y'$ will not remove the conditioning on $x$ and $x'$ respectively. So while it might be possible to arrive at something like $P((x,x'), y)$ by simply looking at $\sum_{y'} P((x, x'), (y, y'))$ getting to $P(x,y)$ might be quite difficult.
How would I best approach this problem?
